# Tmux not loading statusbar config till reload

Tags: terminal, tmux

I have a tmux config with the line `bind r source-file ~/.tmux.conf` where `~/.tmux.conf` is my current tmux config.
This works fine and has a status bar that looks like:

```
 [ cpStudy ] * 96%            ( 0:nvim *)                [  05-12 -  10:56  ]
```

However when i start a new tmux session(often with `tmux`) the config doesn't seem to load properly, and i get the following statusbar

```
[3]               ( 0:zsh *)                  "cpj@cpStudy: ~" 10:58 05-Dec-18
```

Which seems to be a default statusbar, and not the one in the config. Reloading with `prefix+r` gives me the correct bar, so the bound hotkey must be loaded

Comment: In your tmux.conf, are you setting both window-status-format and window-status-current-format?

Answer (score 1):

I use to have the same issue and got very frustrated and at the end I found it's because I was using a theme plugin and after I remove that plugin, the tmux can source the ~/.tmux.conf and apply the status bar style perfectly.

I removed this line in ~/.tmux.conf

```
# theme
set -g @plugin 'jimeh/tmux-themepack'
```

Comment: I do appreciate the answer, however i didn't use any plugins. I don't actually remember how i solved this however

Answer (score 0):

The `tmux` configuration file is sourced when the `tmux` server is started. From the documentation:

```
The configuration file is a set of tmux commands which are executed in
sequence when the server is first started.  tmux loads configuration files
once when the server process has started. The source-file command may be
used to load a file later.
```

The reason your configuration did not apply is probably that there was still at least one active session when you changed your configuration file. You could try closing all the active sessions to stop the server, and then opening a new session to restart the server. (One `tmux` server handles all the sessions, so merely restarting a session is not sufficient to read update the configuration.)

Comment: This still happens from a cold boot however

Comment: what if you try starting `tmux` with `-f ~/.tmux.conf` explicitly. Does it still happen?

Comment: Sorry, I had missed that `prefix+r` works, so the configurations must be read. It might be a syntax error in the configuration?

Comment: But if there is an error. Why would it work on re-sourcing?

Comment: True. Could you paste your configuration, by any chance?

Comment: Here it is: [link](https://pastebin.com/MA0iXmGc)

Comment: Might it be that it is because you didn't include the `-g` flag, and so the options are not applied globally (for all sessions)?

Comment: applied -g flag, Still displays unexpected behaviour

Comment: I'll investigate this weekend. :)